# Use of VARIANT* parameter in ActiveX method in Free Pascal

Tags: c++, delphi, activex, freepascal, idispatch

I would like to use an ActiveX-Object in a Free Pascal project, from the documentation I know that one method is declared as

```
long Fetch(VARIANT* vValue)
```

where vVariant will contain a result (integer or floating point value) after calling.

The LazActiveX "Import type library" function has converted this to

```
_SomeApi = dispinterface
  ['...']
  ...
  function Fetch(vValue: OleVariant):Integer;
  ...
end;
```

I was a bit surprised about OleVariant, because only simple data types should be returned. I also get an EOleSysError (Type mismatch) raised when calling Fetch(v) with v: OleVariant.

Could anyone explain to me how to declare this method in the TLB correctly or how to access the data? Unfortunately, I do not have the source of Fetch() and some of this stuff is covered by an NDA ...

Comment: Has to be an out parameter of type OleVariant. Don't trust the importer. Do it yourself. But OleVariant is right. The fact that the variant only contains simple types doesn't change the fact that its a variant.

Comment: Try this: function Fetch(vValue: ^TVarData):Integer;

Comment: Don't trust the importer. Trust Mr Heffernan. Using "var" parameters did the job, thank you!

Comment: Please file a bug with relevant TLB if you find a bug in the importer.

Comment: I would love to, but this TLB is subject to a non-disclosure agreement. Will an abstract description as above help, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The import process resulted in an erroneous declaration. It should be:

```
function Fetch(out vValue: OleVariant): Integer;
```

if the semanics are OUT, and

```
function Fetch(var vValue: OleVariant): Integer;
```

if the semanics are IN/OUT.

Of course, either of those will work, but you can use var or out to express intent to the caller.